# monacaのcordovaのバージョンを上げたら一部、英語表記になった

Tags: javascript, monaca, html

現在、monacaでアプリを開発しています。
今まで、cordova5.2を使っていましてそろそろバージョンを上げたほうがいいと思い6.2に
しました。6.2にしたところ、iosで日本語だった部分が英語に変わってしまいました。
それはプルダウンでiosではpickerの右上の言語が5.2では完了でしたが、Doneに変更されました。
またwindow.openを使用したときも同じ現象が起きました。
以下にプログラムと画像を載せます。

```
 <select>
  <option>1月</option>
  <option>2月</option>
  <option>3月</option>
  <option>4月</option>
  <option>5月</option>
  <option>6月</option>
  <option>7月</option>
  <option>8月</option>
  <option>9月</option>
  <option>10月</option>
  <option>11月</option>
  <option>12月</option>
</select>
```

[image: picker]
私としては日本語にしたいのですがcordovaのバージョンを上げたらなぜ、英語になったのでしょうか？
ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cordova`というよりプロジェクトの問題のような気がします。
最近Monacaを触っていないので適当ですが、
`MonacaApp-Info.plist`を開いて`CFBundleLocalizations`を追加・編集します。
下記のように入力して日本語を追加して変化ありませんでしょうか？

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>ja</string>
</array>
```

---

[Custom Config プラグイン](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/third_party_phonegap/custom_config/)のドキュメントがあったので少し見てみましたが、
CordovaプラグインのXMLの書き方そのもののようですね。
それでしたら、下記のように記載すれば反映されるものと思われます。

```
<platform name="ios">
    ～中略～
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleLocalizations" overwrite="true">
        <array>
            <string>ja</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
    ～中略～
</platform>
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。どうやらcordova6.2ではMonacaApp-Info.plistファイルが使用できなくなったみたいです。iosの設定を変更するためには、Custom Config プラグインを追加して、config.xml 内に記述するようです。ただ、Custom Config プラグイン使い方がわからず調べている状態となっております。

Comment: 追記しました。参考にしてください。

Comment: 上記のプログラムで日本語になりました。ありがとうございました。